# Undefined reference to `main' - Eclipse using libxml2

Tags: c, eclipse, libxml2, undefined-reference

I am trying to compile a program in C using eclipse and I have an undefined reference to 'main' error, but my code has a main.

The linker is using:  -nostartfiles , -nodefaultlibs , -nostdlib

It was using -c but I erased it because it gave me other errors

Output:

```
make all 
Building file: ../crc.c
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
gcc -I/usr/include/libxml2/libxml -O0 -g3 -Wall -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"crc.d" -MT"crc.d" -o "crc.o" "../crc.c" -I/usr/include/libxml2 -lxml2 -lz -lm
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld devolvió el estado de salida 1
make: *** [crc.o] Error 1
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xmlmemory.h>
#include "crc.h"

#define BIT_SINCRONIA 0X47
#define PID_PAT 0X00
#define table_pat 0x00

FILE *fp2;

int main() {
            //I erased too much lines of code just
        unsigned long crc123 = crcFast(aux, strlen(aux));
        printf("The crcFast() is %X\n", crcFast(aux, strlen(aux)));
        sprintf(aux + strlen(aux), "%X", crcFast(aux, strlen(aux)));
        printf("\nTrama es %s\n", aux);
        printf("ad %X", crc123);

        crc1 = (crc123 & 0xff000000) >> 24;
        crc2 = (crc123 & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
        crc3 = (crc123 & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
        crc4 = (crc123 & 0x000000ff);
        fputc(crc1, fp2);
        fputc(crc2, fp2);
        fputc(crc3, fp2);
        fputc(crc4, fp2);
        fclose(fp2);

    }
    return 0;

}
```

Other function: (In this function I have "Type XX could not be resolved"( XX = xmlDocPtr,xmlNodePtr, etc) and "Field YY could not be resolved"(YY = xmlChildrenNode,name,etc)

```
void XMLdataCatcher(int argc, char **argv) {

    xmlDocPtr doc;
    xmlNodePtr root;
    xmlNodePtr node;
    xmlNodePtr children;
    xmlNodePtr children2;
    char bit_error[1024] = "as";

    doc = xmlParseFile("/home/practicante/XML/prueba1.xml");
    if (!doc) {
        printf("Error al cargar documento XML\n");
    }

    root = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);
    node = root->xmlChildrenNode;
    while (node != NULL ) {
        children = node->xmlChildrenNode;
        while (children != NULL ) {
            if (!(xmlStrcmp(node->name, "bit_error"))) {
                printf("%s: %s\n", node->name, xmlNodeGetContent(node));
                printf("%s\n", bit_error);
                strcpy(bit_error, xmlNodeGetContent(node));
                printf("%s\n", bit_error);
//              bit_error = atoi(xmlNodeBufGetContent(node);
            }
            children2 = children->xmlChildrenNode;
            while (children2 != NULL ) {
                printf("%s: %s\n", children->name, xmlNodeGetContent(children));
                children2 = children2->next;
            }
            children = children->next;
        }
        node = node->next;
    }

    printf("bit_error2 = %d", 1);

//  return (1);
}
```

There is another function called crc.c and the header crc.h but I think they are irrelevant.

I don't know what could be the problem here, I look on the internet but I can't find an answer for this problem.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

[EDIT]
The output with -c:

```
gcc -I/usr/include/libxml2/libxml -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"dataCatcherXML.d" -MT"dataCatcherXML.d" -o "dataCatcherXML.o" "../dataCatcherXML.c" -I/usr/include/libxml2 -lxml2 -lz -lm
../dataCatcherXML.c: En la función ‘XMLdataCatcher’:
../dataCatcherXML.c:17:2: error: nombre de tipo ‘xmlDocPtr’ desconocido
../dataCatcherXML.c:18:2: error: nombre de tipo ‘xmlNodePtr’ desconocido
../dataCatcherXML.c:19:2: error: nombre de tipo ‘xmlNodePtr’ desconocido
../dataCatcherXML.c:20:2: error: nombre de tipo ‘xmlNodePtr’ desconocido
../dataCatcherXML.c:21:2: error: nombre de tipo ‘xmlNodePtr’ desconocido
../dataCatcherXML.c:24:2: aviso: declaración implícita de la función ‘xmlParseFile’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
../dataCatcherXML.c:26:3: aviso: declaración implícita de la función ‘printf’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
../dataCatcherXML.c:26:3: aviso: declaración implícita incompatible de la función interna ‘printf’ [activado por defecto]
../dataCatcherXML.c:29:2: aviso: declaración implícita de la función ‘xmlDocGetRootElement’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
../dataCatcherXML.c:30:13: error: argumento de tipo inválido de ‘->’ (se tiene ‘int’)
../dataCatcherXML.c:31:17: error: ‘NULL’ no se declaró aquí (primer uso en esta función)
../dataCatcherXML.c:31:17: nota: cada identificador sin declarar se reporta sólo una vez para cada función en el que aparece
../dataCatcherXML.c:32:18: error: argumento de tipo inválido de ‘->’ (se tiene ‘int’)
../dataCatcherXML.c:34:4: aviso: declaración implícita de la función ‘xmlStrcmp’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
../dataCatcherXML.c:34:24: error: argumento de tipo inválido de ‘->’ (se tiene ‘int’)
../dataCatcherXML.c:35:5: aviso: declaración implícita incompatible de la función interna ‘printf’ [activado por defecto]
../dataCatcherXML.c:35:28: error: argumento de tipo inválido de ‘->’ (se tiene ‘int’)
../dataCatcherXML.c:35:5: aviso: declaración implícita de la función ‘xmlNodeGetContent’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
../dataCatcherXML.c:37:5: aviso: declaración implícita de la función ‘strcpy’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
../dataCatcherXML.c:37:5: aviso: declaración implícita incompatible de la función interna ‘strcpy’ [activado por defecto]
../dataCatcherXML.c:37:5: aviso: el paso del argumento 2 de ‘strcpy’ crea un puntero desde un entero sin una conversión [activado por defecto]
../dataCatcherXML.c:37:5: nota: se esperaba ‘const char *’ pero el argumento es de tipo ‘int’
../dataCatcherXML.c:41:24: error: argumento de tipo inválido de ‘->’ (se tiene ‘int’)
../dataCatcherXML.c:43:5: aviso: declaración implícita incompatible de la función interna ‘printf’ [activado por defecto]
../dataCatcherXML.c:43:32: error: argumento de tipo inválido de ‘->’ (se tiene ‘int’)
../dataCatcherXML.c:44:26: error: argumento de tipo inválido de ‘->’ (se tiene ‘int’)
../dataCatcherXML.c:46:23: error: argumento de tipo inválido de ‘->’ (se tiene ‘int’)
../dataCatcherXML.c:48:14: error: argumento de tipo inválido de ‘->’ (se tiene ‘int’)
../dataCatcherXML.c:51:2: aviso: declaración implícita incompatible de la función interna ‘printf’ [activado por defecto]
```

Comment: Do you know what the deleted `-c` initiates?

Comment: I just edited the post with the output with -c

Comment: Sorry, I do not speak Spanish. Also I didn't knew gcc does.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing to link an object file exporting `main()`. I suspect you do not compile `main.c`.

---

**Update:**

Does `dataCatcherXML.c` înlcude the necessary headers that come with `libxml`?

Comment: Yes, I write them in the main.c 

"#include <xmlmemory.h>"

Comment: Every translation unit (typical a `*.c` file) needs to include what is needed. So also `dataCatcherXML.c` should have the includes needed.

Comment: How can I link an object file exporting main() ?

Comment: Add a file containing `main()` to your project.

Comment: The `main.c` you show here could be the right file. Did you add to your project? Does it get compiled? I do not see a `main.c` in any of the gcc command you posted so far.

Comment: It's okay now, I don't know what happened :S It's strange I put again -c and put all the headers in the *.C files and now the undefined reference to "main" error dissapear. But the other problem is still there I mean the problem in the XMLdataCatcher:(In this function I have "Type XX could not be resolved"( XX = xmlDocPtr,xmlNodePtr, etc) and "Field YY could not be resolved"(YY = xmlChildrenNode,name,etc)